# Is there an easy for my authenticated users to search other authenticated users?

Tags: 7, views, users, search

I would like to allow my authenticated users the option to search through other authenticated users profiles (like when you allow people to change the filters on a view of content).

I've been searching through modules and documentation for a while now and can't seem to figure out how to solve this problem.

I was hoping that maybe their would be someway to create a view of users? Is that possible? If not, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a default user search. You can go to "your_site/search/user" to try that out. You can set the permissions at "admin/people/permissions" to allow only authenticated users to use this search.